# Angular Material mat-stepper not working with 4 child items

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create a mat-stepper on a new, empty page in Angular

- it does work generally, but disappears when I add the 4th mat-from-field (in step 2)
- the whole mat-stepper won't show up anymore after refreshing the page
- input fields are all bound to a variable through "[(ngModel)]"
- every mat-step has it's own "[stepControl]"
- every form has it's own "[formGroup]"

HTML:

```
<mat-stepper linear labelPosition="bottom" #stepper>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" [editable]="true">
            <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup" class="groupFields">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out Project Info</ng-template>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Project Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="firstCtrl" [(ngModel)]="projectName" required>
              </mat-form-field>

              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Requirements</mat-label>
                <textarea [(ngModel)]="requirements"
                        matInput
                        cdkTextareaAutosize
                        #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                        cdkAutosizeMinRows="5"
                        cdkAutosizeMaxRows="15"></textarea>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Employee Email</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="email" required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div>
                    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" [editable]="true">
            <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
                <div class="customerFrom">
                    <div class="groupFields">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out Customer Info</ng-template>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Customer Name</mat-label>
                            <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" [(ngModel)]="company" required>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="customerAddress" matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>City</mat-label>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="customerCity" matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Customer Type</mat-label>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="customerType" matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup" [editable]="true">
            <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">
                <div class="customerFrom">
                    <div class="groupFields">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel>Add Contacts</ng-template>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>Contact Stuff</mat-label>
                            <input formControlName="thirdCtrl" matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Create Project</ng-template>
            Create the Project or go back and edit!
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> back
                </button>
                <button mat-button (click)="createProject()">
                    <mat-icon>done</mat-icon> create Project
                </button>
            </div>
        </mat-step>
    </mat-stepper>
```

TS:

```
export class ProjectCreationComponent implements OnInit {

  projectName: string = '';
  selectedStatus: string = '';
  requirements: string = '';

  company: string = '';
  customerAddress: string = '';
  customerCity: string = '';
  customerType: string = '';

  forename: string = '';
  surname: string = '';
  address: string = '';
  city: string = '';
  email: string = '';
  mobile: string = '';

  contacts: Contact[] = [];

  unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    thirdCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });


  constructor(
    private service: ProjectService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addContact() {
    let contact = {} as Contact;

    contact.forename = this.forename;
    contact.surname = this.surname;
    contact.address = this.address;
    contact.city = this.city;
    contact.email = this.email;
    contact.mobile = this.mobile;

    this.contacts.push(contact);
  }

  deleteContact(contact: Contact) {
    const index: number = this.contacts.indexOf(contact);
    if(index !== -1) {
      this.contacts.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  createProject() {
    const customer: Customer = {
      name: this.company,
      contacts: this.contacts,
      address: this.customerAddress,
      city: this.customerCity,
      customerTyp: this.customerType
    }

    const announcement: Announcement = {
      requirements: this.requirements,
      customers: [customer],
      offers: [],
    }

    const project: ProjectCreationRequest = {
      name: this.projectName,
      employeeEmail: this.email,
      announcements: [announcement],
      offers: []
    };
    
    this.service.createProject(project)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

I've also exactly tried removing a mat-form-field (so that I only have 3 in the form), for every single one of them, so there is not a specific one that's causing the problem.

One more thing I've tried is changing "[(ngModel)]" to "[value]", because 2 way binding isn't necessarily needed, but with that the value of the textfield can't be stored in the variable.

Also I didn't find anything in the material documentation about a maximum size of step child items or anything.

Stackblitz (not 1:1 because of too many classes): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buspzu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: could you create a stackblitz link for the issue?

Comment: I've updated the post, the link is on the bottom

Comment: wait, you are mixing template form (ngmodel) with reactive form (formbuilder). This is not about mat-stepper, nor about the number of inputs

Comment: So you're not allowed to use an ngModel within a frombuilder? Is there another way to bind the input values to variables in this case?

Comment: oh yes, use reactive form completely. The reason is all of the input's value will eventually go into your form, so basically you're using 1 big form, just cut it to smaller steps

Comment: So, I've tried around a bit now with using only one form for everything. Tbh i got pretty confused on how to setup the Array for the steps. 
But in the meantime I found out that [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" kinda works in my case.. the only problem now is that I can't put a formControllName on my input field and the step-buttons stop working

Comment: What you did is fine, I mean you have your form setup correctly, you just need to replace ngModel with formControlName, like the very first input in each of the step. The option standalone mean the input/form-field isn't related to any form, that's why it works because it no longer attached to any declared formGroup

Comment: Previously, you have some properties in your class, that you use with ngModel. Now, those properties should belong to your form, correct? So you declare them under formbuilder, pass them to the template under formControlName

Comment: Your last two comments did it for me, now everything is working as expected and I finally understand who the stepper is meant to be used. Thank you very much!